# nested list to print specific sections

Tags: python, list

I have the following nested list

```
l = [['TEST', ['parent', [], 'uuid', ['"khk-yyas4h-323223-wewe-343er-3434-www"'], 'display_name', ['"services"'], 'IPV4', ['ip', ['"1.1.1.0"'], 'mask', ['20'], 'type', ['ip_mask']], ['ip', ['"2.2.2.2"'], 'mask', ['32'], 'type', ['ip_mask']]]]]]
```

I am trying to loop through this and only get the following data:

```
1.1.1.0:20
2.2.2.2:32
```

I have been trying everything to get this to work, and can't figure it out

Comment: Is there a reason why you data is a (mallformed) ``list`` instead of a ``dict``? It seems to have key, value structure.

Comment: Its a file that i am given and i need to parse it, is there a way to convert this to a dict?

Comment: Are you sure that there is no comma between `'TEST'` and `['parent', ...`?

Comment: Please show some code you have tried to use, so that we can get a better understanding of what the problem is.

Comment: Yes there is a comma, sorry mistyped it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex on the str/repr of the nested list?

```
import re

data = [['TEST', ['parent', [], 'uuid', ['"khk-yyas4h-323223-wewe-343er-3434-www"'], 'display_name', ['"services"'], 'IPV4', [['ip', ['"1.1.1.0"'], 'mask', ['20'], 'type', ['ip_mask']], ['ip', ['"2.2.2.2"'], 'mask', ['32'], 'type', ['ip_mask']]]]]]

matches = re.findall(r"\['\"(?P<ip>(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})\"'\], 'mask', \['(?P<mask>\d{1,2})'\]", str(data))
print([f"{ip}:{mask}" for ip, mask in matches])
```

Output:

```
['1.1.1.0:20', '2.2.2.2:32']
```

Comment: Wow thanks, that is exactly what i was looking for, but it doesn't seem to work, when i try to print it, from what i found using the f lieral in print function is new in python 3.6, any way of printing this out correctly in python 2

Comment: @Stanll Change `print([f"{ip}:{mask}" for ip, mask in matches])` to `print(["{}:{}".format(ip,mask) for ip, mask in matches])`.

Answer (score 1):

If you format the list like so, the pattern will be easy to spot:

```
l = [['TEST',
      ['parent',
       [],
       'uuid',
       ['"khk-yyas4h-323223-wewe-343er-3434-www"'],
       'display_name',
       ['"services"'],
       'IPV4',
       [
           ['ip', ['"1.1.1.0"'], 'mask', ['20'], 'type', ['ip_mask']],
           ['ip', ['"2.2.2.2"'], 'mask', ['32'], 'type', ['ip_mask']]
        ]
       ]
      ]]


l1 = l[0][1][7][0][1][0].strip('"')+':'+\
     l[0][1][7][0][3][0]
l2 = l[0][1][7][1][1][0].strip('"')+':'+\
     l[0][1][7][1][3][0]

print(l1)
print(l2)
```

Output:

```
1.1.1.0:20
2.2.2.2:32
```

You can see a pattern where only the `0` and the `1` are different, so if you *(If by any chance this is only part of the actual data)* want to find the next set, change that index to `2`.

So you can:

```
for i in range(len(l[0][1][7])):
    print(l[0][1][7][i][1][0].strip('"')+':'+l[0][1][7][1][3][0])
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much for that, just curious though, is there a way to tell how many are in there so i can loop only that amount of times to change the index?

Comment: You can `print(len(l[0][1][7]))`